# Build a matrix to identify a step-wise change in integers for a vector

Tags: r, matrix

I'd like to build a matrix that records the change from one integer value to another for a vector.

**Example Vector**

```
a <- c(NA,1,3,4,2,6,5,3,7,7,NA,3,NA,5,5,NA,2,3,1,4)
```

**Conceptual Matrix Design**

Where I would tally every time a value in the vector `a` changes (or doesn't change) **from** one integer **to** another.

```
               To
         1 2 3 4 5 6 7
       1
       2
       3
From   4
       5
       6
       7
```

**Desired Output**

Note that `NA`'s matter. E.g., `7,NA,3` in `a` does not count for `from 7` `to 3`.

```
              To
         1 2 3 4 5 6 7
       1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
       2 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
       3 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
From   4 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
       5 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
       6 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
       7 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: why 7 7 have 2 ?

Comment: Nice catch! I've corrected, it should only have 1.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Using `table`

```
table(dplyr::lag(a),a)
   a
    1 2 3 4 5 6 7
  1 0 0 1 1 0 0 0
  2 0 0 1 0 0 1 0
  3 1 0 0 1 0 0 1
  4 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
  5 0 0 1 0 1 0 0
  6 0 0 0 0 1 0 0
  7 0 0 0 0 0 0 1
```

Comment: Perfect! I have to wait 10 minutes before accepting...also, I reached my voting max today but I'll make sure to upvote tomorrow.

Comment: @NickDylla no worry , glad I can help , happy coding

Comment: Base R: `table(head(a, -1), tail(a, -1))`

Answer (score 2):

```
dict = sapply(2:length(a), function(i) toString(a[(i-1):i]))
unq = sort(unique(a))
+t(sapply(unq, function(x) sapply(unq, function(y) toString(c(x, y)) %in% dict)))
#     [,1] [,2] [,3] [,4] [,5] [,6] [,7]
#[1,]    0    0    1    1    0    0    0
#[2,]    0    0    1    0    0    1    0
#[3,]    1    0    0    1    0    0    1
#[4,]    0    1    0    0    0    0    0
#[5,]    0    0    1    0    1    0    0
#[6,]    0    0    0    0    1    0    0
#[7,]    0    0    0    0    0    0    1
```

Answer (score 2):

An option with `tidyverse`

```
library(tidyverse)
tibble(a, a1 = lag(a)) %>% 
   dplyr::count(a, a1) %>% 
   filter(!is.na(a), !is.na(a1)) %>% 
   spread(a1, n, fill = 0) %>% 
   column_to_rownames('a')
#  1 2 3 4 5 6 7
#1 0 0 1 0 0 0 0
#2 0 0 0 1 0 0 0
#3 1 1 0 0 1 0 0
#4 1 0 1 0 0 0 0
#5 0 0 0 0 1 1 0
#6 0 1 0 0 0 0 0
#7 0 0 1 0 0 0 1
```